# Выборка кол-ва комментариев к постам

Tags: sql, mysql

Всем привет! У меня такой вопрос:

Есть 2 таблицы posts, comments в БД(MySQL). В таблице comments есть поле post_id(id поста из posts), как мне посчитать кол-во комментариев для каждого поста, условие: нужно выбрать одним запросом, чтобы результат был вида:

```
post | comments_count
Пост | 23
```

Я туплю просто, простая задача, но не могу реализовать, запутался. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
select post, count(*) as comments_count
from posts p join comments c on p.id = c.post_id
group by p.id, post
```

Если нужны посты без комментариев тоже, поменять join на left join, и count(*) на count(post_id).
[Группировка](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_group_by_clause.html)